# How can I perform a List<object>.Cast<T> using reflection when T is unknown

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting

I've been trying to do this for a good few hours now and this is as far as I have got

```
var castItems = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast")
                  .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { targetType })
                  .Invoke(null, new object[] { items });
```

This returns me

> System.Linq.Enumerable+d__aa`1[MyObjectType]

whereas I need (for my ViewData) as generic list i.e.

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyObjectType]

Any pointers would be great

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just need to call ToList() on it afterwards:

```
static readonly MethodInfo CastMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast");
static readonly MethodInfo ToListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList");

...

var castItems = CastMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { targetType })
                          .Invoke(null, new object[] { items });
var list = ToListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { targetType })
                          .Invoke(null, new object[] { castItems });
```

Another option would be to write a single generic method in your own class to do this, and call *that* with reflection:

```
private static List<T> CastAndList(IEnumerable items)
{
    return items.Cast<T>().ToList();
}

private static readonly MethodInfo CastAndListMethod = 
    typeof(YourType).GetMethod("CastAndList", 
                               BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

public static object CastAndList(object items, Type targetType)
{
    return CastAndListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { targetType })
                            .Invoke(null, new[] { items });
}
```

Comment: Thanks completely forgot that (code blindness had set in) thanks.

[btw to be complete there is a typo in your method for anyone who may want to copy any paste should say var list =ToListMethod.MakeGen.....]

Comment: Brilliant. Hard to find, but totally solved my problem. Thanks all.